# How to Structure Search Facets on Dynamic Fields

Tags: search, aggregate, azure, indexing

I am responsible for implementing search functionality for our web application; I take search text from a user and come up with a list of products, score them, and return them to display to the user. The search itself works fine, however, the team wants to be able to guide the user's search by way of presenting filters to the user, along with facets displaying filter options and counts. I have run into trouble with the facets in particular, and would appreciate guidance in how to implement them.

#### Background:

- For this search functionality, management has pushed for use of Azure Cognitive Search, and that is what I have used thus far. If ACS is the wrong tool for the job (as I feel it might be) I need to be able to present a strong case as to why and offer an alternative.
- The data (Azure SQL) we are searching over contains ~10 million products. Each product has a number of attributes (~10-100 each). Products within the same category have the same attributes, but might have different values, i.e. books all have attributes for "genre" and "length" but may have different values like "fantasy"/"sci-fi" and "short"/"long". Across all categories, there are currently 10 thousand unique attributes, but, as stated, only 10-100 apply to a single product.
- When a user searches for a product, we want to allow the user to narrow down their search by showing what types of attribute values exist in the results, along with their distribution. For example, searching for "Young Adult Fiction" might yield filters like

  - Genre

    - Fantasy (120)
    - Sci-fi (65)
  - Length

    - Short (50)
    - Long (135)

#### The Problem

Azure Cognitive Search provides some facet functionality out of the box, specifically allowing facets to be calculated across the result set on stated fields. This works fine for certain fields, such as category and manufacturer, which belong to all products and exist in limited number. However, this is more difficult for attributes, which are potentially unbounded in number and vary between products. It appears, just from experience and documentation, that each attribute must be its own field in order to be facetable, but also each field must exist for **every** product. This means creating 10s of thousands of fields, most of which will contain null values, as well as maintaining/adding fields as attributes are modified/added. Unwieldy as it is, it is theoretically possible, although practically, well, read on.

#### What I've Tried

- Packing a JSON or other delimited/structured object containing only the relevant attributes into a single field. This works fine for searching on, as ACS supports Regex searches, but not for faceting or aggregating result statistics, as ACS does not support more complex result aggregation.
- Creating an index with a field for each attribute which is sparsely populated. The limitation here was the database side, as compiling the available data into a view exceeded the column limit of 1024, and sparse columns do not appear to be available within views. Even querying such data outside of the context of a view appeared unwieldy.
- Creating an index with a complex field on a JSON containing each attribute which is sparsely populated. Again, the limitation here was database side. The view compiled successfully, however, querying such a view proved impossible. ACS allows a maximum 30 minute timeout for queries, and at 30 minutes SQL had only yielded about 10 thousand of the 10 million entries. The limitation here seems to be the massive size of the JSON, which is being transmitted from the server as an uncompressed VARCHAR(MAX) with a length of ~100 thousand characters.

#### What I want

- Can I structure my data in such a way that I can compute facets on an arbitrarily large set of attributes?
- Can Azure Cognitive Search compute statistics on the result set in a more sophisticated manner?
- Is there a significantly better tool for the job?

Thank you in advanced!